# Escaping whitespace in regular expression with ply?

Tags: python, regex, escaping, whitespace, ply

Do I need to escape a single white space in a regular expression? I know it works either of the following ways in Python: `re.compile(r'\s')`, `re.compile(r' ')`and `re.compile(r'\ ')`. So it seems that you can either escape it or not with Python re module.

But when I was trying to define a rule for a single whitespace via ply.lex, things seem to be a little different.

```
##########################
# r'\s' works with ply.lex
def t_WHITESPACE(token):
  r'\s'
  pass

##########################
# r'\ ' also works 
def t_WHITESPACE(token):
  r'\ '
  pass

##########################
# r' ' DOES NOT work 
# A SyntaxError was raised with the message "Regular expression for rule 't_WHITESPACE' matches empty string"
def t_WHITESPACE(token):
  r' '
  pass
```

Does ply.lex make any special processing with the rule's **doc** string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know ply, but this looks like it compiles the regex using the [`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.X) option which means you do need to escape literal whitespace or use `\s`.

Also, you need to escape hashes (`#`) or the following parts will be interpreted as comments.

Comment: Yes, I found the use of re.VERBOSE in ply source code! Thank you very much!